# git clone inside docker files are not downloaded after

Tags: git, docker, github, dockerfile, containers

I created a Dockerfile that looks as follows:

```
FROM node

ARG SSH_KEY

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install git
RUN apt-get -y install openssh-server

RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
     chmod 0700 /root/.ssh && \
     ssh-keyscan github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts


# Add the keys and set permissions
RUN echo "$ssh_prv_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
      echo "$ssh_pub_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
      chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
      chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
      ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/    
      ADD id_rsa.pub  /root/.ssh
      RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
      RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

      WORKDIR /app

      RUN git config --global http.sslverify false

      RUN git clone git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git /app
```

I create image with:

```
      docker build -t python-cleanup .
```

and then I run the docker with:

```
      docker run -ti   -v C:\github\decrypt-cleanup-docker:/app python-cleanup
```

the problem is that after running the docker I cannot see the file from the github repo.

but, if I run the docker with the following command:

```
    docker run -it -v C:\github\decrypt-cleanup-docker:/app python-cleanup git clone git@github.com:myorg/myproject.git
```

then the files appears in the /app folder

what I am doing wrong or not understanding properly?

Comment: when you build docker, it should be cloned. but your mount path overrides the cloned dir.

Comment: A `docker run -v` mount _always_ hides the content in the image and replaces it with content from the host; bind mounts do not go the opposite direction and you can't use them to edit content built into the image from the host.  You should probably run `git clone` from your host; this avoids problems with Docker caching the `git clone` step, and it avoids accidentally compromising your ssh key by publishing it in the image.

Comment: Set the clone command as an entrypoint or cmd instruction